# using scala Find four elements from list that sum to a given value

Tags: scala, list, functional-programming

I am new to scala programming language and want to implement the code having below scenerio.
given a list sampleone of n integer and an integer samplethree, there are elements a,b,c and d in sampleone such that a+b+c+d = samplethree. Find all unique quadruplet in the list which gives the sum of samplethree

Example:

```
sampleone =[1,0,-1,0,-2,2] and samplethree = 0 
a solution set is 
[-1,0,0,1]
[-2,-1,1,2]
[-2,0,0,2]
```

the code that I have used is

```
scala> def findFourElements(A: List[Int], n: Int, x: Int) = {
     | {
     | for(a <- 0 to A.length-3)
     | {
     | for(b <- a+1 to A.length-2)
     | {
     | for(c <- b+1 to A.length-1)
     | {
     |  for(d <- c+1 to A.length)
     | {
     | if(A(a) + A(b) + A(c) + A(d) == x)
     | {
     | print(A(a)+A(b)+A(c)+A(d))
     | }}}}}}
     | }
findFourElements: (A: List[Int], n: Int, x: Int)Unit


scala> val sampleone = List(1,0,-1,0,-2,2)
sampleone: List[Int] = List(1, 0, -1, 0, -2, 2)

scala> val sampletwo = sampleone.length
sampletwo: Int = 6

scala> val samplethree = 0
samplethree: Int = 0

scala> findFourElements(sampleone,sampletwo,samplethree)
0java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
  at scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.apply(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:65)
  at scala.collection.immutable.List.apply(List.scala:84)
  at $anonfun$findFourElements$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$2$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$3.apply$mcVI$sp(<console>:33)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
  at $anonfun$findFourElements$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$2.apply$mcVI$sp(<console>:31)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
  at $anonfun$findFourElements$1$$anonfun$apply$mcVI$sp$1.apply$mcVI$sp(<console>:29)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
  at $anonfun$findFourElements$1.apply$mcVI$sp(<console>:27)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:160)
  at findFourElements(<console>:25)
  ... 48 elided
```

But I am getting error of index out of bound exception.
Also is there a way to have a more optimized code in scala.

Thanks for help.

Comment: `to` generates an inclusive range (`d <- c+1 to A.length` includes `A.length`, which is beyond the array boundary). You can use `until` instead of `to` ... But don't do that. You rarely need to spell out loops like that in scala. See the answer below for an idea on how it can be done better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may do what you want:

```
sampleone.combinations(4).filter(_.sum == samplethree)
```

> The `combinations` method gives an iterator that delivers each possible combination of values in turn. If there is more than one way to construct the same sequence, only one will be returned.

The `filter` call removes any sequences that do not sum to the `samplethree` value.

Comment: thanku..I wonder its just a one line code...instead of using 4 for loops and if as in java and other languages..